# Mounting exFAT drive on Fedora 35 requires specifying device

Tags: fedora, filesystems, exfat

I am running Fedora 35 and am trying to mount an exFAT drive, specifically an SD memory card for my digital camera.

The computer identifies the card reader as device `/dev/sde1` and I am trying to use `/lacie2` as the mount point.

This works correctly: `sudo mount /dev/sde1 /lacie2` and I am able to access the drive. Typing `mount` shows the drive as:

```
/dev/sde1 on /lacie2 type exfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0022,dmask=0022,iocharset=utf8,errors=remount-ro)
```

However, I tried writing an fstab entry to `/etc/fstab` as:

```
/dev/sde1          /lacie2         exfat   user,noauto,shortname=lower  0   0
```

so I could mount the drive directly with `sudo mount /lacie2`. This doesn't work but gives the error:

```
mount: /lacie2: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

What is the reason here? As Fedora obviously seems to be able to mount exFAT drives, why must I explicitly specify the device?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mount fails because `shortname` is not a supported option for exfat (that's a [vfat](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/filesystems/vfat.html) option). Remove it from your `fstab` and you should be able to mount the device.

> wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/sde1, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.

In general, if you get this error (and the device you are trying is formatted to a supported filesystem), you should always check the kernel log for the "other error" part, in this case you should see something like:

> kernel: exfat: Unknown parameter 'shortname'

Comment: Thanks! That worked, and also allows me to mount the drive without using sudo.

Comment: That's what the `user` option in `fstab` does.